# Handlebars.js calendar and urls

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

for a 30 day "pop up" event I'm using handlebars and jquery to load each day 'data' (media, text...) from json files. So far works as expected :

```
        //template

<script id="calendarT" type="x-handlebars-template">

<ol id="calendar"class="cf">{{#each list}}<li class="day" >{{this}}</li>{{/each}}</ol>      
<div id="progress"><div id="bar"> </div></div>  
</script>

//data + compile

var allDays  = {"list":["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"]};   
var calT = Handlebars.compile($("#calendarT").html());
$("#calendarView").html(calT(allDays)); 


    //using moment.js we highlight today etc... and update bar's width


var isnow = moment().date();
$("#calendar li:eq("+isnow+")").addClass("on");    
$("#calendar li:gt("+isnow+")").addClass("future");   
$("#calendar li:lt("+isnow+")").addClass("past");        
if (isnow<7) {
 $('#bar').css('width', "15%");}
else if (isnow>=7&isnow<=14) {
$('#bar').css('width', "20%");} 
else  (isnow>=14&isnow<=24) {
$('#bar').css('width', "60%");}
//you get the idea, this should be improved, something like $('#bar').css('width', isnow+"%") ??? 
}); 

        //load day on click
$ui.on('click', '.past', function(event) { var today = $(this).text();  
$.getJSON('days/'+today+'.json', function(data) {                     
var eachdayT = Handlebars.compile($("#eachdayT").html());
$("#dayView").html(eachdayT(data)).toggle();          
 });
```

What I'd like to do next is to add some sort of 'url routing' (or is it called 'state'?) so that if user type on a browser .com/popupevent/#22 I can show/load that day's contents. It will also help I guess for Like/retweet buttons...

So far seems to work on firefox/safari, is there a better way to do it? Is it possible to get rid of the hash .com/popupevent/22 ?

```
 if ( window.location.hash==="") {
    // do nothing
    }else{              
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    alert("haz hash and is "+hash+"") ; 
// load day
    }
```

GRACIAS.

[image: screenshot]
 [image: caniuse.com]

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history), also there is a good plugin that provides support for older browsers and fixes inconsistencies. https://github.com/browserstate/history.js

If you are developing a single web application I would recommend using [Backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone) plugin that has a Routing API and supports History API.

Comment: Undefined, it's doesn't feel necessary for this specific scenario to use History API (I did have a look at http://davidgoss.co.uk/2011/08/06/ajax-paging-with-jquery-and-the-history-api/ & https://github.com/mtrpcic/pathjs & https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-bbq & http://davisjs.com). My first thought was to use ember.js (easy project to get my way into the framework) but again what is needed is a couple of handlebars templates so I don't think It's worthy.

Comment: hello again, do you see any problem using something like this ?
`if ( window.location.hash==="") {
alert("no hash"); 
}else{    
 
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);    
alert(""+hash+""); 


$.getJSON('days/'+hash+'.json', function(data) {                     
var eachdayT = Handlebars.compile($("#eachdayT").html());
$("#dayView").html(eachdayT(data)).toggle();     
});`

Comment: the smart folks at staceyapp.com use:  var stripped_url = document.location.href.match(/([^\/]+)\/(#.+)?$/)[1];